# Increasing the output current of a buck switch mode power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I built a small buck switch mode voltage regulator, I obtained an output of 5 volts exactly which was what I wanted, but then the output current is very small, it can't even charge a mobile phone. I sourced the circuit from a car battery. can anyone guild me on how to increase the output current. below is the circuit diagram.
[image: Buck switch mode voltage regulator]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/switchmode3.gif?x98918))</sub>

I will be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: Hard to do without a schematic.

Comment: I have added a schematic, please can you help?

Comment: That doesn't help that much.  None of the parts have values, and you don't show what generates the pulses or regulates them to keep the voltage constant.

Comment: I used an op amp comparator IC 741, with 5 volts reference voltage at the non-inverting input of the comparator, and the inverting input of the comparator connected directly to the output. then the output of the comparator turns off or turn on the transistor to keep the voltage constant.

as for the value of the transistor, l used TIP41C, the capacitor, I used 100uf. I didn't actually include  
the inductor

Comment: The inductor is just about the most important component... you'll also need to mention the switching frequency...

Comment: Please can you clarify me on the importance of the inductor in relation to the output current. Also please throw more light on how the switching frequency comes into play. I will be grateful if you do. Thanks

Comment: From your decription, you haven't built a switching regulator.  Your description sounds more like you have built a linear regulator.  You have nothing to generate pulses, and the inductor (which you left out) is the very heart of a buck regulator.

Comment: Without an oscilloscope, you can't verify that your PCB layout is switching correctly (proper ground return management is critical), nor can you verify the inductor's current is ramping up and down as designed (inductor LI-squared energy storage is also critical; an audio choke won't work for SMPS). Take a look at TI's "simple switcher" parts, they have good applications support and can provide a bill of materials.

Comment: 1. Please include any updates in the question itself. New readers shouldn't have to read the comments to understandt the question. 2. Change the schematic to show what you actually built. Don't expect us to read through a bunch of text to understand what's different between your schematic and your actual circuit. That's worse than no schematic at all.

Comment: -1 for a schematic that is completely different from the circuit you actually want to ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used an op amp comparator IC 741, with 5 volts reference voltage at the non-inverting input of the comparator, and the inverting input of the comparator connected directly to the output.

This is not a switching regulator, this is a linear regulator.

> then the output of the comparator turns off or turn on the transistor to keep the voltage constant.

This is not what will happen. The '741 isn't being operated as a comparator, because you have provided negative feedback (by connecting the output to the inverting input). The '741 output will maintain a slowly varying voltage as necessary to keep the output voltage at the desired voltage, not switch on and off.

> Please can you clarify me on the importance of the inductor in relation to the output current.

The inductor stores energy when the input voltage is connected, and releasees it (continuing to provide current to the load) when the input voltage is disconnected. But this is irrelevant to your circuit since you aren't actually switching the control voltage on and off.